# PHP Get File By Regexp

Tags: php, regex, file-management

Is there a way that I can have PHP get a file by a Regexp search? I know how to open and read a directory no problem, but finding a particular file *is* the problem.

Here is an example, I have a logo which may end in any of the following extensions: `.bmp`, `.png`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, or `.gif`. However, the name of the file will *always* be `icon.someext`.

```
$filesDirectory = scandir("/files");

foreach($filesDirectory as $file) {
    [Regexp find logo here] ? $logo = $file : null;
}

echo $logo; // Returns something like logo.png
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried glob? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184444/how-to-list-directories-which-name-starts-with-a-digit-php/3184529#3184529

Comment: Nope, but it looks like you nailed it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) with wildcard and `GLOB_BRACE`:

```
$files = glob("icon.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$files = glob("icon.*");
```

works pretty much like wildcarding on a unix command line does.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `preg_match()`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

If you need help using it, let me know.